# map values to 3 object variables from 3 different select statements in ssis

Tags: variables, ssis, task

I want to map values to 3 object variables from 3 different select statements by using single executesqltask.

Is that possible?

Comment: I suppose you could if you could use something like a CTE to return a single set of results once all 3 statements have been processed.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by applying a join between the three SQL statements using a fake ID.  Here are the steps:

1. In the SQL Task Editor set the ResultSet to "Single row".
2. Enter your SQL statement something like that below, which will return a single row with three columns (each column is a result of a single record and column from the three joined SQL statements).

   ```
   SELECT 
       a.test1, 
       b.test2, 
       c.test3
   FROM 
       (SELECT top 1 '1' as ID, field_A as test1
       FROM [dbo].[table1]) a
       JOIN (  SELECT top 1 '1' as ID, field_B as test2
               FROM [dbo].[table2]) b
           on a.id = b.id
       JOIN (  SELECT top 1 '1' as ID, field_C as test3
               FROM [dbo].[table3]) c
           on a.id = c.id
   ```
3. Select Result Set and add three new results names "0", "1" and "2".  Each one will map to one of the three variables names you've defined in the package.  You must use result names of 0, 1 and 2.  "0" matches that returned from the first column of the SQL statement, "1" from the second column and "2" from the third column.

Hope this helps and please indicate if this answers your question.

Comment: My apologies.  I just noticed after posting the above that the three variables are of type "object".  Given that, my suggested solution will not work.  Is there a reason why this must be performed in a single SQL Task, instead of three separate tasks?

Comment: my proc produces 3 result sets, thats why. No issue to split but in a curiosity I asked